# How to add "Starting at:" price prefix for configurable products?

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, price, products

For grouped products, prices are prefixed with "Starting at:" - I'd like to do the same thing for configurable products. I'm thinking the file I want is `app/design/frontend/mytheme/default/template/catalog/product/price.phtml`, but I'm having trouble getting it to work. I tried changing this:

```
$showMinPrice = $this->getDisplayMinimalPrice();
```

To this:

```
$showMinPrice = $this->getDisplayMinimalPrice() || $_product->isConfigurable();
```

But no luck.

Answer (score 1):

It also checks for a value in the `$_minimalPriceValue`. Just give that the `FinalPrice` value which should be the base price for the configurable product

```
$showMinPrice = $this->getDisplayMinimalPrice();
if ($_product->isConfigurable()) {
    $_minimalPriceValue = $_product->getFinalPrice();
}
if ($showMinPrice && $_minimalPriceValue) {
    $_exclTax = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_minimalPriceValue);
    $_inclTax = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_minimalPriceValue, true);
    $price = $showMinPrice ? $_minimalPriceValue : 0;
} else {
    $price = $_convertedFinalPrice;
    $_exclTax = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $price);
    $_inclTax = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $price, true);
}
```

Comment: Tried this but doesn't seem to work. Having trouble finding something that does, this file is a mess. (I did verify this is the correct template file, replacing the whole thing with "test" works)

Comment: I know them feels, actually made a `price.phtml` without WEEE that makes it a bit better https://gist.github.com/sandermangel/de408f7bbea33c8b7771

Comment: @fpcjh try ading some `var_dump(__LINE__);`'s here and there to find out where what code is used